# Trying to span both rows and columns in an HTML table

Tags: html

I am trying to create a table in HTML that does both row and column spanning. I've nailed most of it, but the upper right has two blank rows that I would like to span. Here's what I have so far (it's a confusion matrix--that's an understatement):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"></th>   
    <th colspan="2">Class</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"></th>   
    <td>Loyal</td>
    <td>Churn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Pred. class</th>
    <td>Predicted loyal</td>
    <td>TN</td>
    <td>FN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Predicted churn</td>
    <td>FP</td>
    <td>TP</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is that possible? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: i can´t see any blank rows in the upper right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the upper left right?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" rowspan="2"></th>   
    <th colspan="2">Class</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>   
    <td>Loyal</td>
    <td>Churn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Pred. class</th>
    <td>Predicted loyal</td>
    <td>TN</td>
    <td>FN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Predicted churn</td>
    <td>FP</td>
    <td>TP</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j0Ln2uwm/

Comment: Dyslexics untie! Thanks very much.